# Has anyone combined marginfix and tikzmark yet?

Tags: tikz-pgf, marginnote

I am working on a big book project, and up until today I refrained from using glue. But now I had to, and, lo and behold, suddenly my margin notes' position is broken :( The reason is that `marginfix` doesn't work with glue because it positions the notes before the glue is calculated (or so it seems to me). The `marginfix` author promised to use pdfsavepos somewhen in the future, but unfortunately I need it now.

I have now had a look at many other questions and packages, but I could not find an adequate replacement for `marginfix` - or did I miss something? I did, however, find `tikzmark`, which is cool. But I didn't find a package that uses `tikzmark` to position simple, plain margin notes exactly next to the call-out line, rearranging them nicely if there are too many.

Before I will write my own code or try to understand marginfix, I would like to know if there are some solutions available already?

***UPDATE:***

I have been trying to use `\pdfsavepos` using David's example... I do get the data, but I really don't understand the values. If they are `sp`, what is the reference point, what the coordinate system? Even when I convert them to pt by diving by 65536, the values are totally different than what `marginfix` calculated.

I replaced the `\MFX@getypos` of marginfix with this:

```
\newcounter{mfixcnt}

\def\MFX@getypos{%
    \refstepcounter{mfixcnt}%

    \pdfsavepos
    \edef\tmp{%
        \write\noexpand\@auxout{%
            \string\mfixdata{\the\c@mfixcnt}{\noexpand\thepage}{\noexpand\the\noexpand\pdflastypos}}%
    }\tmp


    \expandafter\ifx\csname mfixins@\the\c@mfixcnt\endcsname\relax
        \dimen@\dimexpr\@pageht+\@pagedp+\marginposadjustment+\Mfx@mparshift\relax
\typeout{NOT YET: \the\c@mfixcnt -- \the\dimen@ -- \the\@pageht -- \the\@pagedp -- \the\Mfx@mparshift}
    \else
        \dimen@\dimexpr\csname mfixins@\the\c@mfixcnt\endcsname+\marginposadjustment+\Mfx@mparshift\relax
    \fi

    \ifnum\outputpenalty=-10002\relax
        \advance\dimen@-\Mfx@strutheight
    \fi
    \edef\mfx@ypos{\the\dimen@}%
    \global\Mfx@mparshift\z@
}

\def\mfixdata#1#2#3{%
    \typeout{XXXXXXXX mpardata called: #1 -- #2 -- #3}%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname mfixins@#1\endcsname{#3sp}%
}
```

The output is

```
XXXXXXXX mpardata called: 1 -- 1 -- 42094230
XXXXXXXX mpardata called: 2 -- 1 -- 29740694
XXXXXXXX mpardata called: 3 -- 1 -- 11685526
```

How come the values decrease for margin notes that (should) be further down on the page? This could only be if the pdf coordinates have the origin on the bottom of the page. Is that so?

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{geometry}


\geometry{left=2.5cm,textwidth=130mm}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{4cm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{2em}

\usepackage{marginfix}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulpu-
tate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi
tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris
ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibu- lum urna
fringilla ultrices.XX\marginpar{\textbf{This note is centered because
there is enough space below and it is in the middle of a paragraph.}} Erat
ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl
hendrerit mollis.
Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Nam arcu
libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulpu- tate a, magna. Donec
vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et
netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis
vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum,
erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et
nisl hendrerit mollis.Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellen- tesque
a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullam- corper
vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus
mauris.XX\marginpar{\textbf{This note is pushed upwards because it is at
the end of a pragraph}}

Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at,
tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec
nonummy pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin
fermentum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a,
molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at,
accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc
eleifend consequat lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque
tincidunt purus vel magna. Integer non enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu
purus. Donec bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec
et mi. Nam vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu
massa.

Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vi- tae
lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tempus con-
vallis augue. Etiam facilisis. Nunc elementum fermentum wisi. Aenean
placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat
quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus
nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae risus porta
vehicula.XX\marginpar{\textbf{This note is automatically adjusted by
`marginfix'.}} Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum massa ac
quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo.
Maecenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a,
ipsum. make ot just a bit longer to show it moving better.
bibendum,
nulla a vel justo vi- tae lacus tinci dunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec,
suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc eleifend
consequat lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque tincidunt
purus vel magna. Integer non enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Donec
bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam
vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu massa.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You really use no stretchable glue? you have fixed spaces for displays and floats and parskip etc? On a large book the standard `\marginpar` isn't so bad really, it can have problems near ends of pages but in a book you look at those anyway, it's different of you are typesetting thousands of lines of machine generated data and need a fully automatic solution. For an old answer here I made a pdfsavepos (aka tikzmark) based margin note solution which is available  [here](https://code.google.com/p/dpctex/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fmpnote) but it's probably not production quality yet.

Comment: yes - 820 pages, and lots and lots of margin notes. I only use `0.5\onelineskips` that are problematic, all others are interger multiples of `\onelineskip`s. Quite fantastic and really good looking, but if there is an uneven number of `0.5\onelineskips` on a page, the text ends half a line too soon on the page. So I need a little bit of glue there... I'll have a look at your solution. I have also figured that marginfix is determining the position in `\MFX@getypos`, storing it in `\mfx@ypos`. Now just how to adapt that...

Comment: Ok, I have to admit, I had to give up on this for now, it takes too much time to figure everything out... but the good news is, while reading package code to see how others have been doing it, I accidentally came across the marginnotes package, which I didn't know before. That package has no trouble at all putting the notes exactly where they should be. On pages where I need automatic adjustment of margin stuff, I use marginfix. So I am done for now - until a bright person is able to fix marginfix...

Comment: You shouldn't set layout dimensions manually if using either KOMA *or* `geometry` - let alone both.

Comment: yeah, you may be right, but it is just a simple MWE. I guess I could have used `article` or `minimal`, too. My actual document uses `memoir`.